# Using user defined function as boolean expression

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

How to use user defined function as boolean expression ?

For example function `REGEXP_LIKE()` used as  boolean expression, right?

`... WHERE REGEXP_LIKE() ...`

But how to make such for user defined function?  When  my function returns BOOLEAN type and then, when I call this function, I got error because pure SQL can't use BOOLEAN type.

P.S.

So, I do this: my function returns `VARCHAR2` type: that is `'TRUE'` or `'FALSE'` and then in SQL I use: `... WHERE my_function() = 'TRUE' ...`

This is right way for simulate boolean type? or exists more better  solutions  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This can be confusing in Oracle but SQL does NOT know boolean datatype, although it deals with boolean expressions. Unlike procedural PL/SQL where boolean datatype can be used.

In Oracle SQL and PL/SQL are evaluated by different engines. These engines use similar datatypes, but not the same.

Comment: So, in SQL, simulating boolean type using varchar, that is: `WHERE my_function() = 'TRUE'` is a normal way ?

Comment: Yes. You can even create your own "operator" in Oracle. But even operator work the same way.

Comment: Maybe when you return a `NUMBER` instead of `VARCHAR2` from your function it will be a little bit faster.

Comment: @Ivan I'd go for return type NUMBER instead of VARCHAR2 - simpler and cleaner IMO.